# Change values within AWS Glue DynamicFrame columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to change values within some columns of my DynamicFrame in a AWS Glue job.
I see there is [a Map function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html) that seems useful for the task, but I cannot make it work.

This is my code:

```py
    def map_values_in_columns(self, df):
        df = Map.apply(frame = df, f = self._map_values_in_columns)
        return df


    def _map_values_in_columns(self, rec):
        for k, v in self.config['value_mapping'].items():
            column_name = self.config['value_mapping'][k]['column_name']
            values = self.config['value_mapping'][k]['values']

            for old_value, new_value in values.items():
                if rec[column_name] == old_value:
                    rec[column_name] = new_value
            return rec
```

My config file is a yaml file with this structure:

```yaml
value_mapping:
    column_1:
        column_name: asd
        values:
            - old_value_1: new_value_1
            - old_value_2: new_value_2
    column_2:
        column_name: dsa
            - old_value_1: new_value_1
            - old_value_2: new_value_2
```

The above method throws a serialisation error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o81.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

I am not sure if this is due to how I am implementing the Map method, or if I should use a completely different approach.

So the question:
**How can I change multiple values within multiple columns using AWS DynamicFrame, trying to avoid conversion back and forth between DynamicFrames and DataFrames?**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code and yaml config, I'm not going to debug them here. See a working sample below, this can also be executed [locally in a jupyter notebook](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/).

I have simplified the yaml to keep the parsing complexity low.

```py
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
columns = ["id", "asd", "dsa"]
data = [("1", "retain", "old_val_dsa_1"), ("2", "old_val_asd_1", "old_val_dsa_2"), ("3", "old_val_asd_2", "retain"), ("4", None, "")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
dyF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "test_dyF")

import yaml
config = yaml.load('''value_mapping:
    asd:
        old_val_asd_1: new_val_asd_1
        old_val_asd_2: new_val_asd_2
    dsa:
        old_val_dsa_1: new_val_dsa_1
        old_val_dsa_2: new_val_dsa_2''')

def map_values(rec):
    for k, v in config['value_mapping'].items():
        if rec[k] is not None:
            replacement_val = v.get(rec[k])
            if replacement_val is not None:
                rec[k] = replacement_val
    return rec

print("-- dyF --")
dyF.toDF().show()
mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame = dyF, f = map_values)
print("-- mapped_dyF --")
mapped_dyF.toDF().show()
```

````
-- dyF --
+---+-------------+-------------+
| id|          asd|          dsa|
+---+-------------+-------------+
|  1|       retain|old_val_dsa_1|
|  2|old_val_asd_1|old_val_dsa_2|
|  3|old_val_asd_2|       retain|
|  4|         null|             |
+---+-------------+-------------+

-- mapped_dyF --
+-------------+-------------+---+
|          asd|          dsa| id|
+-------------+-------------+---+
|       retain|new_val_dsa_1|  1|
|new_val_asd_1|new_val_dsa_2|  2|
|new_val_asd_2|       retain|  3|
|         null|             |  4|
+-------------+-------------+---+```
````